# blazemeter recording cannot be run because of 401 error

Tags: jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have recorded some screen interactions (with VPN turned off) using blazemeter.
When I try to run the jmx file that the blazemeter created, I am hit by a 401 error.

Here are the 3 steps-

1. Load the website
2. Login
3. Go to a specific screen

Only the 'Load the website' works. The login and the 'go to specific' screen fails.
Same result with or without VPN.

I checked for CSRF token but I don't see any token value in the response. I only see '{var CSRFToken=top.i2ui_shell_content.results.csrfToken;var finalURL=url+"&"+"T_ID_TOKEN="+CSRFToken;top.i2ui_shell_content.results.location=finalURL}' but not the token value specifically.

Error-
<!doctype html>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorizedbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized

**Type** Status Report

**Description** The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

#### NA

What am I missing?